# how to get question_id count value based on two tables using mysql

Tags: mysql

I want count for chat_question_id from chat_questions table based on user_id=1 in chat table.

Below is my chat_questions table

```
chat_question_id  user_id
1                 1
2                 1
```

and the chat table

```
chat_id  chat_question_id  user_id
1        1                 1
2        1                 1
3        2                 1
```

below is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(cq.chat_question_id) 
FROM chat_questions AS cq 
LEFT JOIN chat AS c ONc.chat_question_id = cq.chat_question_id 
WHERE c.user_id =2
```

Comment: and what's your question ... you have errors? ... no result  .. ?  wrong result  .. .. and post text data not image ..

Comment: You have typo. "LEFT JOIN chat AS c **ONc**.chat_question_id". Can you fix it (add space after ON) and try it again?

Comment: Hi I  want count for chat_question_id.

Comment: you have not user_id 2 in c table (chat)  ..

Comment: I am getting the count of chat_question_id= 3 based chat because in chat table There is 3 columns thats my problem i want to get chat_question_id=2

Comment: I am not clear why you need to join the 2 tables if all you want is a count of chat_quesion_id = 2 - you could just use the chat table with a where chat_question_id = 2?

Comment: Why is there a `user_id` in `chat` when there is already one in `chat_questions`? Can they be different? How are the tables related? By `chat_question_id` only? (Which is what I would assume from the names.) Or by `chat_question_id` plus `user_id`?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Please show more records with more users and then show us the expected result. Do you want to count the number of records in one of the tables? Or count distinct questions?